# How to set up WSO2 Identity Server and API Manager cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to set up WSO2 Identity Server cluster and an other for WSO2 API Manager. Identity server will be used to enable SSO for our applications and also to register existing Identity Providers (ex: ADFS). API Manager will be used to manage our Rest API's and to provide them to our applications. I also want to configure the Identity Server to be the Key Manager.

As the documentation says for WSO2 Cluster deployment, Management nodes are specialized in management of the setup, while worker nodes are specialized in serving requests to deployment artifacts. Besides that, API Manager product provides 5 diferent profiles (key-manager, publisher, store, gateway-manager and gateway-worker).

For now, I have 3 servers (server1, server2 and server3) in which I will install and configure the WSO2 Cluster nodes for Identiy Server and API Manager. I also created a load balancer that will be used to forward requests for each cluster nodes (IS and AM).

After some reading, I concluded that I would need to install WSO2 IS and WSO2 AM as manager nodes on the server1 and the two other servers would be used as worker nodes.

I think I already managed to install and configure Identity Server cluster, the url *`mgt.identity.mydomain.pt`* points to the server1 node and *`identity.mydomain.pt`* points to server2 and server3 nodes for load balancing requests.

Now I'm stuck with API manager cluster configuration, I want to use server2 and server3 as the gateway to load balance requests (*`apis.mydomain.pt`*) for our Rest API's and use server1 to manage our API's using store and publiser components (*`mgt.apis.mydomain.pt`*). I'm struggling to understand which profile I have to use for each nodes. I tried to install a manager node on server1 with the default profile and install worker nodes on the server2 and server3 with the gateway-worker profile but I'm getting errors related to the Deployment Synchronizer ([error logs](http://pastebin.com/Jc0QhkLg)). I guess I am doing something wrong because those errors only shows up when using the gateway-worker profile.

Anyone can explain me the difference between worker and manager nodes and how they are related with wso2 profiles?

**UPDATE:**

I found out what I was missing and was causing the error. I was starting the server2 and server3 just with -Dprofile=gateway-worker, I added -DworkerNode=true and I have no errors in log anymore.

Anyway, I am still a little bit confused about using the gateway-manager and gateway-worker profiles.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer contains Deployment synchronizer related configurations. Can you check whether you configured the manager and worker nodes correctly

Comment: I checked again and those configurations were ok. I think I might found the problem. I was missing the -DworkerNode=true